# Distriqt Dialog ANE - aapt failed (error finding resources)

Tags: android, dialog, air-native-extension, distriqt

I've just tried to use the distriqt dialog ANE on Android (a Nexus 5 device with Android 6.0)
I've added the ane as usual and included it in the application.xml 
When I try to compile I'm getting the following:

```
aapt tool failed:C:\Users\SeanJD\AppData\Local\Temp\bbea1b25-409e-40dd-84bb-a8411a70231c\distriqt-extension-dialog-res\values-v21\distriqt_dialog_themebase.xml:16: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material'.
C:\Users\SeanJD\AppData\Local\Temp\bbea1b25-409e-40dd-84bb-a8411a70231c\distriqt-extension-dialog-res\values-v21\distriqt_dialog_themebase.xml:20: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.Dialog.Alert'.
C:\Users\SeanJD\AppData\Local\Temp\bbea1b25-409e-40dd-84bb-a8411a70231c\distriqt-extension-dialog-res\values-v21\distriqt_dialog_themebase.xml:4: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Dialog.Alert'.
C:\Users\SeanJD\AppData\Local\Temp\bbea1b25-409e-40dd-84bb-a8411a70231c\distriqt-extension-dialog-res\values-v21\distriqt_dialog_themebase.xml:7: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
C:\Users\SeanJD\AppData\Local\Temp\bbea1b25-409e-40dd-84bb-a8411a70231c\distriqt-extension-dialog-res\values-v21\distriqt_dialog_themebase.xml:5: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
C:\Users\SeanJD\AppData\Local\Temp\bbea1b25-409e-40dd-84bb-a8411a70231c\distriqt-extension-dialog-res\values-v21\distriqt_dialog_themebase.xml:6: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
```

Any thoughts on what could be causing this?

Thanks
Sean

Answer (score 1):

This was due to the Dialog ANE requiring the v20 of the AIR SDK (I was using v19) There is an older version of the Dialog ANE (compatible with older versions of AIR) at https://github.com/distriqt/ANE-Dialog/releases